# How to create a scatter plot with numerous points in editable eps format?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a 2-D array of shape (371, 1014) which contains 371*1014 points. I want to fit them in a scatter plot with codes as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(1014)
for i in range(371):
    y = data[i][x]
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=y, s=1, vmin=-0.02,vmax=0.02, cmap='bwr')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

plt.savefig('scatter.eps', format='eps')
```

[image]

With ***plt.show()***, the plot can show normally as the figure above. After ***savefig()***, however, only a broken or blank eps file of less than 1KB is created. My purpose is to create a editable figure with eps or some other format. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try to call saving before show.

Comment: @RazmikMelikbekyan Thanks it works! But the created eps file is over 35MB which is too big. Any suggestions to reduce the file size?

Comment: I assume this due to a lot of data points and selected format.